# How to calculate the gas flow rate?

Tags: flow-control, compressed-gases

I am using a Venturi burner fed using a lpg cylinder. I need to calculate the gas flow rate?
I am thinking of filling the gas in a balloon/fixed container can take the weight before and after to get the difference to get the weight of the gas. Buoyancy and shape may affect this. Averse to using this way due to weighing machine hacking. This can be suitable for Venturi if I take a relatively big container so that gas pressure doesn't increase substantially when venturi output is fed.

Can use  pv = nrt. Prefer this method using balloons as not at the mercy of hackers and less calculation pertaining to initial air, vacuum etc.

Balloon should be around atmospheric pressure when inflated and stable. What will be a fair assumption? I can weigh the lpg cylinder as well with very sensitive scales. Same repeated with air + gas. This will give me the approximate output at Venturi burner. My ultimate goal is to calculate the MJ generated. I have to go through all this hoopla because my temperature meter is hacked (readings tampered through wireless).

Else would have relied on the temperature meter.

The conditions of ballon and open air may be different.

One major issue is my weighing machine is hacked. The readings cannot be trusted. Any suggestions to overcome this. Thinking of covering it in mylar space blanket and recording using an airgapped device.

Balloons facing issues with Venturi due to a small mouth of balloon. Bigger mouth balloon is needed.

Comment: Why not use an actual flow meter ? like a vane / propeller type device or ball in a vertical tube type device or a Venturi device ... Why Mylar banket ? What do you mean by *hacked* ? Please elaborate by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: but why would you be safe from the flow meter hackers?

Comment: I cannot trust any meter.

Comment: Not even the weighing machine.

Comment: Pretty sure the scale will be more accurate and consistent than the gas regulator feeding the burner. Just time how long it takes for a 20 pound cylinder to empty.